# Which one to use? EAV or Blobs in the database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I am currently working to rework the data system of our application. Basically, it is designed so that people can add all the custom fields they want, with only a few constant/always-there fields.

Our current design is giving us plenty of maintenance problems. What we do is dynamically(at runtime) add a column to the database for each field. We have to have a meta table and other cruft to maintain all of these dynamic columns.

Now we are looking at EAV, but it doesn't seem much better. Basically, we have many different types of fields, so there would be a StringValues, IntegerValues, etc table... which makes things that much worse.

I am wondering if using JSON or XML blobs in the database may be a better solution, specifically because in most use cases, when we retrieve anything out of these tables, we need the entire row. The problems is that we need to be able to create reports for this data as well.. No solution really makes custom queries look easy. And searching across such a blob database will surely be a performance nightmare when reports are ran.

Each "row" needs to have anywhere from about 15 to 100(possibly more) attributes/columns associated with it.

We are using SQL Server 2008 and our application interfacing with the database is a C# web application(so, ASP.Net).

what do you think? Use EAV or blobs or something else entirely? (Also, yes, I know a schema free database like MongoDB would be awesome here, but I can't convince my boss to use it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about the xml datatype? Advanced querying is possible against this type.

We've used the xml type with good success. We do most of our heavy lifting at the code level using linq to parse out values. Our schema is somewhat fixed, so that may not be an option for you.

Comment: I'm going to research this more and talk to my boss about it, but it looks like this is exactly what we need

Comment: Another option is to return xml from your relational tables inline with your query using FOR XML, and you can then deserialize it at the object level.

Answer (score 1):

One interesting feature of SQL server is the [`sql_variant`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx) type. It's fully supported in .NET and quite easy to use. The advantages is you don't need to create StringValue, IntValue, etc... columns, just one Value column that can contain all the simple types.

This very specific type favors the EAV option, IMHO.

It has some drawbacks though (sorting, distinct selects, etc...). So if you want to use it, make sure you read all the documentation and understand its limit.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with your known columns and "X" sparse columns using a sequential name such as DataColumn0001, DataColumn0002, etc.  When there is a definition for a new column just rename a column and start inserting data.  The great advantage to the sparse column is it is indexable.

More info at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx).

Comment: 100 sparse columns don't seem good.. and that's basically what we are doing now that is ending up to be a maintenance nightmare

Answer (score -5):

What you're doing is STUPID with a database that doesn't support your data type. You should work with a medium that meets your needs which include NoSQL databases such as RavenDB, MongoDB, DocumentDB, CouchBase or Postgres in RDMBS to name several.

You are inherently using the tool in a capacity it was neither designed for, and one it specifically attempts to limit you from achieving success. NoSQL database solutions frequently use JSON as an underlying storage because JSON is inherently schemaless. Want to add a property? Sure go ahead, want to add a whole sub collection? Sure go ahead. NoSQL databases were in part, created specifically to remove rigid schema requirements of RDBMS.

2015 Edit: Postgres now natively supports JSON. This is a viable option for RDBMS. My answer is still correct that you need to use the correct tool for the problem. It is a polygot persistence world.

Comment: Your answer is STUPID with this question.

Comment: Read the last sentence of my question. I noted that a non-relational database would be awesome, but I am forced to use SQL Server for the time being

Comment: /shrug bring on DVs, I stand by my answer. This is the right answer. Your boss is certainly allowed to be wrong.

Comment: @Chris - actually this is not the right answer, since it doesn't address the OP's question.  He says, within SQL server which he is constrained to, what's the best solution.  You may ask "What's the fastest American car?" and I can say "Get a Bugatti Veyron, it's the fastest!".  That's accurate but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @JNK strawman argument. Your question actually would be along the lines of asking what's the fastest car and then having to say wait I only want ones that have 17 rectangular wheels.

Comment: @Chris - fair enough, but the Veyron is still not the correct answer TO THE QUESTION.

Comment: Please explain why it is stupid and how it would be done in NoSQL.  If it is stupid, give a concrete example of a better design in NoSQL.

Comment: "A fanatic is one who can't change his mind and won't change the subject." - Winston Churchill